# ¿Cómo acceder a impresoras en la red desde una web api publicada en IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Estoy migrando una aplicación de escritorio a la web, tengo una web api creada con asp.net core, la idea es poder disparar impresiones desde el api cuando sea necesario, esto lo hago utilizando los comandos de winspool. Cuando ejecuto mi proyecto en visual studio, puedo acceder a cualquier impresora, sin embargo cuando publico mi aplicación en mi IIS local, no logro imprimir en ninguna impresora, asumo que es un tema de permisos e investigando encontré que hay unos usuarios que se pueden configurar en el pool del sitio, existe uno llamado Local System el cual debería de tener altos privilegios, sin embargo esto no funciona. Intenté la configuración de <> usando mi usuario local en el web config, sin embargo nada de esto me ha funcionado. ¿A alguien le ha ocurrido?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: tienes que hacer que tu aplicacion reconosca las impresoras locales que ve tu serviddor ... esto se lleva a cabo en tu backend en que estas programando c#???

Comment: La impresora de quien? del usuario o del servidor? una app de escritorio no tiene nada que ver con una app web...

Comment: Las impresoras las agrego manualmente usando el administrador de dispositivos, de esta manera accedo a ellas localmente usando winspool, y ese es el asunto, no tengo idea de a qué o a quién debo darle permisos para que pueda comunicarse con las impresoras, estas estan compartidas para todos en la red, por lo que en teoría debería de funcionar. @gbianchi lo siento, no me quedó claro lo de <<una app de escritorio no tiene nada que ver con una web>>

Comment: Si @ArcanisGK507 estoy utilizando C#

Comment: @AlexVarela a ver normalmente en un ambiente linux yo colocaria el archivo en un directorio conocido y mediante comandos LP enviaria a imprimir el archivo ... asumiendo que C# es tu lenguaje de backend independientemente que sea el lenguaje proveedor de tu sitio web; debe tener alguna opcion para hacer lo mismo.

Comment: no se si @gbianchi tenga una buena solucion en la manga del saco de .net

Comment: aqui hay un hilo sobre el tema del 2015 aprox: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/43b594b4-81aa-478b-b705-69a56ba508d2/how-to-connect-remote-printer-in-aspnet?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: esa es exactamente la manera en la que me conecto utilizando winspool, el asunto es que logro conectarme a las impresoras cuando corro el proyecto en visual studio, pero una vez lo publico en IIS dejo de ser capaz de imprimir, asumo que es un tema de permisos, de ahi la pregunta. Gracias por el articulo igual está interesante lo del queue.

Comment: Igual acepto cualquier sugerencia de alguna otra librería que me permita acceder a las impresoras de esta manera. Intenté con la librería ESC/POS pero esta solo funciona con impresoras de red o por puerto serial, no con impresoras USB compartidas por la red.

Comment: a ver.. es importante entender algo... en un ambiente web, tenes 2 partes.. un servidor, y un cliente... el codigo del servidor, se ejecuta en el servidor dentro de IIS... por eso te digo que una app de escritorio no tiene nadaaaaa que ver.. en una app de escritorio, todo se ejecuta en el mismo lugar. Vamos por partes. tu problema entonces es como generar un usuario en IIS que tenga acceso a las impresoras usb agregadas donde? en el usuario o en el servidor?

Comment: Ya entendí a lo que te refieres pues es en el servidor, tengo las impresoras configuradas en la BD y y sé qué impresora utilizar en qué situación, si el cliente manda una petición, la api generará el recibo y lo imprimirá en la impresora que corresponde todo esto ya está hecho en este caso la impresora estará agregada en el servidor, esta puede estar conectada por usb a otra computadora o puede simplemente ser una impresora por IP, etc.